Breaking up a dexie query into individual statements
How can I build up a dexie query in individual parts, rather than all in one line?
In particular, I only want to apply .reverse() if some condition is set, and of course I need to apply that after the filter and before the offset and limit.
In SQL, I would create a queryBuilder, and then keep adding to it based on the condition, but I can't find any examples of how to do that in dexie, everything's all in one statement.
queryBuilder = db.friends;
if (reverse) {
    queryBuilder.reverse();
} 
queryBuilder.offset(10).limit(5).toArray().then( (results) => ...);

is NOT the same as
db.friends.reverse().offset(10).limit(5)

But that's what I'm striving for.
